# View Pager without Fragment not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So I'm trying to use a viewpager to swipe between screens. I'm trying to do this without using a fragment but I cannot get it to work. I'm getting an error on line 59 which is    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);  for a null pointer exception when I try to set my adapter. I was going off of an example I found on here. I think I'm in over my head with this, this is my first time trying to use a view pager.

heres my Route details activity where I'm trying to set the adapter

```
public class RouteDetails extends AppCompatActivity {


CustomPagerAdapter mCustomPagerAdapter;
ViewPager mViewPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_route_details);

    dbHandler = new MyDBHandler(this, null, null, 1);


    //route detail xml array info
    final CharSequence[] routeDetail= getResources().getTextArray(R.array.routeDetail);

///array of route images
    final TypedArray image = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.routeImages);

    ///////

    mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(this, routeDetail, image);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);

    ///////
}
```

and heres my CustomPagerAdapter

```
class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

CharSequence[] routeDetail;
TypedArray routeImageId;
Context mContext;
LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, CharSequence[] routeDetail, TypedArray routeImageId) {
    mContext = context;
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.routeDetail = routeDetail;
    this.routeImageId = routeImageId;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return routeDetail.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_route_details, container, false);

    TextView routeText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.routeDetailsView);
    routeText.setText(routeDetail[position]);

    final int imageId = routeImageId.getResourceId(position, 0);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.routeImage);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageId);

    container.addView(itemView);
    return itemView;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
}
```

}

Thanks for any help!

edit: adding relvant xml files

activity_route_details.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_route_details"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.zach.BirdsboroClimbing.RouteDetails">


<CheckBox
    android:text="Route Climbed"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/routeCheckBox"
    android:gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/routeDetailsView"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_below="@id/routeCheckBox"/>


<ImageView
    android:layout_below="@id/routeDetailsView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/routeImage"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

pager_route_details.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and routeListViewItems.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string-array name="routeDetail">
 <item><b>Shark Bait - 5.9</b>\n\n \u25BA 2 draws + 2 for anchor.\n</item>
    <item><b>Rain Check - 5.8</b>\n\n \u25BA 3 draws + 2 for anchor.\n</item>
    <item><b>Rain Check Direct - 5.8</b>\n\n \u25BA 4 draws + 2 for anchor.\n</item>
    <item><b>Arocknophobia - 5.7</b>\n\n \u25BA 3 draws + 2 for anchor.\n</item>
    <item><b>Balls Deep - 5.9+</b>\n\n \u25BA 3 draws + 2 for anchor.\n</item>
    <item><b>Jingle Bells - 5.9</b>\n\n \u25BA 4 draws + 2 for anchor.\n</item>
    <item><b>Itching to Climb - 5.8</b>\n\n \u25BA 5 draws + 2 for  anchor.\n</item>

</string-array>

<integer-array name="routeImages">

<item>@drawable/sharkbait</item>
<item>@drawable/raincheck</item>
<item>@drawable/raincheckdirect</item>
<item>@drawable/arocknophobia</item>
<item>@drawable/ballsdeep</item>
<item>@drawable/jinglebells</item>
<item>@drawable/itchingtoclimb</item>

</integer-array>
</resources>
```

The way I want it to work is, I have a listview main activity, when you select an item in the list view it opens up the corresponding position of the route detail view pager activity, from there I want to be able to swipe to the previous or next item.

Thank you!

Comment: can you provide more info like the logs. We don't even know what line 59 is.

Comment: Sry line 59 is    mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter); I'll post the full log when I get to my computer

Comment: I tried Implementing your code myself, it looks OK and it works for me can you post your relevant XML files so I could maybe see what is the problem.

Comment: hey thanks for checking I still cannot get it to work. I added all the relevant files you asked for in my original post. Thanks

Comment: typed in wrong place

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting ur activity layout as activity_route_details.xml which does not contain viewpager item but pager_route_details

In RouteDetails.java change this line

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_route_details);
```

with

```
setContentView(R.layout.route_details);
```

Comment: thanks so I tried your code and now I'm getting an error on line 36 of my CustomPagerAdapter which is  public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    } the error is java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ScrollView cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
                      at com.example.zach.BirdsboroClimbing.CustomPagerAdapter.isViewFromObject(CustomPagerAdapter.java:36)

Comment: Try removing the cast. The `==` doesn't need you to cast the object or use the `equals` method instead of the `==` in any case remove the cast I don't think it's necessary

Comment: I figured it out! I did change to view.equals(object); but then I was getting an error on line 41 saying Scroll view can only have one direct child so then I Nested the button,textview,and imageview inside another linear layout. I also had to Change my relative layout to a linear layout. And lastly I had to Move the scrollview from Outside the first linear layout to inside the Linear layout. But I'll accept uguboz response as the correct answer since that got me past my initial error. Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things that could cause you problems

A. You are not using the correct layout for your `RouteDetails` Activity you should inflate the one with the `ViewPager` in it

```
R.layout.pager_route_details
```

instead of

```
R.layout.activity_route_details
```

B. Inside your Adapter you should remove the cast to `LinearLayout` The `==` operator doesn't require you to cast the items. I'd advise you you use

```
view.equals(object)
```

Should work now.